# Airplanes Parking On Taxiway

Tags: faa-regulations, faa, airplane, taxiways

I've noticed one or two planes at my airport continuously park on the Taxiway and stay for sometimes an hour+. I keep looking and can't seem to find any regulations on this topic. (Only finding stuff about taxiway construction) Can someone find me something released by the FAA regarding this issue. Are they to be fined or just told "move it".

Comment: Who owns the airport?  Is there an airport manager?  This is probably best resolved at the local level.

Comment: During The Master's golf tournament one taxiway is lined with parked aircraft. Here's some shots (from the Twitter video): https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.golfdigest.com/story/masters-tournament-2022-augusta-regional-airport-private-jet-video/amp

Comment: during the covid travel restrictions and the airspace closure after 9/11 many airports had taxiways and runways used as parking space for hundreds of aircraft, often for weeks or months at a time. In some cases this actually caused problems for the structural integrity of the taxiways.

Answer (score 3):

If it's an airport with a Control Tower, access to the taxiway is controlled by ATC.

If it is an airport without a control tower, then concerns about aircraft parking on a taxiway would probably best be addressed with the entity that owns the airport (City, County, State, Port Authority, etc.).

The airport manager would likely be a good initial point of contact to  whom you could voice your concerns.

Under the conditions and circumstances specified in 14 CFR 91.13 (b), that regulation may apply.

[14 CFR 91.13 (b)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-91) states:

> **(b) Aircraft operations other than for the purpose of air navigation.**  No person may operate an aircraft, other than for the purpose of air navigation, on any part of the surface of an airport used by aircraft for air commerce (including areas used by those aircraft for receiving or discharging persons or cargo), in a careless or reckless manner so as to endanger the life or property of another.

Comment: Hm. Does that mean that if you *are* operating an aircraft "for the purpose of air navigation" then you *are* allowed to operate  it in a careless or reckless manner on any part of the surface of an airport used by aircraft for air commerce? That's certainly how I would read it.

Comment: @randomhead I  think it means if you are operating an aircraft "for the purpose of air navigation"  you would refer to FAR 91.13 (a), which covers that.

Comment: @randomhead, sometimes legalese like this is intended that each clause stand alone.  i.e. "No person may operate an aircraft other than for the purpose of air navigation." and:  "No person may operate an aircraft on any part of the surface of an airport used by aircraft for air commerce."  and:  "No person may operate an aircraft in a careless or reckless manner..."  I can't swear that that's the intent, because I can get to your alternate interpretation as well.

Comment: @MichaelHall 91.13 (b), I believe,  is designed to apply to a variety of non-Air Navigation careless or reckless events.  For example, if a taxi-qualified mechanic is taxiing a B737 from a gate to a maintenance hanger (never entering an ATC controlled movement area) and clips the tail of another aircraft or hits a parked fuel truck the mechanic might be subject to a violation of 91.13 (b). Lots of examples I can think of where 91.13 (b) would likely apply.  It's to cover non-Air Navigation airport surface incidents.

Comment: An aircraft being parked isn't "being operated for the purpose of air navigation", is it? If the pilot taxied it there and turned off the engine maybe that'd be covered, if it were towed it wouldn't be afaik.

Comment: @jwenting  Don't know for sure how that would be interpreted.  But the word in the regulation is ..."no person may **operate**." Not the same as being **operated** or **operating**,  So I don't know if it would apply. If you parked your airplane in the middle of a 2000 ft runway at night and got out and walked away endangering other pilots who might land and not see your airplane in time to avoid it, did you **operate** your airplane in a careless manner?

Comment: I think bringing 91.13 into this just takes us down a rabbit hole.  I'm guessing this is some small, un-towered, municipal or private field, just call the airport manager or speak to the pilot directly and ask them not to park like a jerk and block others.  No need to play FAA lawyer.  I'd upvote if it was trimmed down to just the first three paragraphs.

Comment: @MichaelHall since the op was asking if there were any regs on the topic I added 91.13 (b) because it covers operations not for the purpose of air navigation. I don't know if that reg would apply to the airplanes being parked on taxiway but it may have some relevance depending on the circumstances.  I am not looking for upvotes, just providing info in response to the question.